# Table view marking more than one cell Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a VERY annoying problem.

I have a tableView with more or less 50 cells, displaying some options to which I can select the ones I want. I read in Apple's documentation that by default the cells are reused when they are not displayed. With this, if I select the first cell, every 6 cells 1 is marked, that is, if I select the first 6 cells, ALL cells in the table are marked!

My table view allows multiple selections. The selection is being made like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
}
```

How do I solve this? I know you have such a "prepareForReuse ()" for the subclass, would that be the solution? If so, can you give me an example of how you would do it?

Comment: can you show some more code.??

Comment: You can take one Mutablearray. When user clicks one cell then store that cell's indexpath into that array and when same cell selected again then check that indexpath already in array if yes then remove indexpath from array or add indexpath into array

Comment: @Jecky Modi I completely agree with your answer that is the best solution.

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is code it may help you

```
var arr_selectedindePath = NSMutableArray()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if arr_selectedindePath .contains(indexPath) {

            arr_selectedindePath .remove(indexPath)
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        else
        {
          arr_selectedindePath .add(indexPath)
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        if arr_selectedindePath .contains(indexPath) {
           cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        else
        {
          cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your example worked perfectly, my friend. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update your data model accordingly so that when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called it displays cells with updated content.

If you don't use a datamodel you will need to store the indexPath's in a mutable array and make a check whether the current indexPath is marked or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

**In your custom cell**

**1**.**Create a delegate**

```
protocol CellDelegate {

    func didTapOnButton(_ cell:Cell)

}
```

**2**. **Declare delegate**

```
var delegate:CellDelegate?
```

**3.Override this method**

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.delegate = nil
    }


@IBAction func buttonTapped()
{
    self.delegate!.didTapOnButton(self)
}
```

**In your tableview controller**

**1.Implement delegate method**

**2.Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath assign tag value to cell.button**

**3.implement this method**

```
 func didTapOnButton(_ cell: Cell) {
                print("off button clicked at index \(cell.button.tag)")

            }
```